# how to style primeng tooltip

Tags: angular, tooltip, primeng

I had tried by giving custom class & tool tip Style Class to the tooltip it does not work for this

[image: 1]

Comment: Please do not show code as picture. Also, if someone answer to your question, don't forget to clic on the check mark on top left of answer

Comment: [pTooltip}="item.col1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
   <button
                pButton 
                type="button" 
                class="p-button-raised p-button-rounded p-button-success"
                label="Tooltip Button" 
                pTooltip="Hello World !" 
                tooltipPosition="bottom">
   </button>
```

**CSS**

```
.p-tooltip .p-tooltip-text {
    background-color: grey !important;
    color: green !important;
}
```

**or better to use :host ::ng-deep without important**

```
:host ::ng-deep .p-tooltip .p-tooltip-text {
    background-color: grey;
    color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can style `PrimeNG` tooltips by adding some css in tooltip classes or along with any custom class.

[image]

An working example is [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tooltip-demo-zy25pf?file=src/styles.css)